# Bulk Insert or Bulk Update from a table to another (n) Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a source table that has tons of columns.
I would like to extract records from this source table and insert/update into another (n) table.

Currently I am using deterministic methods such as the following:

```
MERGE ClassTbl AS Target
USING SourceTbl AS Source
ON Source.[ClassCode] = Target.[Code]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target
THEN INSERT (
    [Code]
    ,[Description]
) VALUES (
    Source.[ClassCode]
    ,Source.[ClassDescription]
)
WHEN MATCHED AND Source.[ClassDescription] <> Target.[Description]
THEN UPDATE
SET Target.[Description] = Source.[ClassDescrition];
```

The problem with the above code is that it inserts a new record even if the same ClassCode already exists in ClassTbl.Code.
Thus, having duplicate records.

The following are how my data models looks like:

**SourceTbl**

```
...
ClassCode,
ClassDescription,
...
CompanyCode,
CompanyDescription,
CompanyOtherColumn
...
```

**ClassTbl**

```
Id
Code
Description
...
```

**CompanyTbl**

```
Id
Code
Description
OtherColumn
...
```

With all that being said,
How can I bulk insert or update from my source table to my other table i.e., ClassTbl and CompanyTbl?

Comment: *"Problem with the above code is that, it inserts even if the same classcode already exist"* Then your `JOIN` is incorrect or tghe values are in fact different; the above `MERGE` will only `INSERT` a new row when no row in `ClassTbl` is found with a value of `Code` when matched against `SourceTbl`'s `ClassCode` value. Though, i do suggest a read of [So, you want to use MERGE, eh?](https://sqlblog.org/merge); at least follow its advise and implement a `HOLDLOCK`.

Comment: @Larnu that is also bugging me. I have checked the code many times there should be no problem with the join. I only set "classcode" from source and then "code" from target.
P.S The actual code above is exactly the same as my code just change the names for the general public.

Comment: @Larnu I even tried adding a unique index to *code* column but instead received the following error. "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo...' with unique index '...'. The duplicate key value is (00001100).
The statement has been terminated." Why do the statement go to insert clause? when it shouldn't?